# Let $a, b, c, d$ be positive integers satisfying $ab=cd$. Prove that $a+b+c+d$ ݀ is composite.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I started with an even odd arguement, where I tried to show that no matter which numbers you pick, the sum would always be even. However, this doesn't work for the arrangment of 3 evens and one odd. Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 2):

Write $p=a+b+c+d$ and say $p$ is prime. Then we have $$ab=c(p-a-b-c)$$ so $$(a+c)(b+c) = cp$$
which means that $$p\mid a+c\;\;\;\;{\rm or}\;\;\;\;p\mid b+c$$
in 1st case we get $p=a+b+c+d\leq a+c$ a contradiction. The same contradiction we get in the second case. So $p$ must be composite.

Comment: Where did you get $ab=c(p-a-b-c)$ from? And how does that leaed to $(a+c)(b+c)=cp$?

Comment: $p=a+b+c+d$ so $d= p-a-b-c$...

Comment: @GerardL. as for the second half of your question, multiply out $c(p-a-b-c)$ and then move the last three terms to the LHS.